# Lista simplesmente encadeada - Problema no método

Tags: c++, lista

Estou tendo um problema com o método `delete_find_number` do meu código.

É o seguinte: este método deve excluir um número especifico que é passado como parâmetro. Após receber o parâmetro, este método chama um outro método chamado `findNumber` para fazer a busca do valor e verificar se ele existe.

Quando adiciono três valores à minha lista e peço que o programa delete um valor e, caso esse valor seja o último da lista, o programa dá *crash* e fecha (o mesmo acontece se o valor for o primeiro da lista). Se for um valor intermediário, ele exclui corretamente.

---

EDIT:Modifiquei algumas coisas no codigo,removi o metodo find e passei toda a tarefa de deletar para o método `delete_find_number`,adicionei o delete aos nós que foram eliminados da lista e adicionei a verificacao para testar se o valor procurado esta em head ou tail.

Porem, se tento utilizar o método `delete_find_number` quando  a lista tem apenas um elemento, o programa da crash. Se eu testar com 3 elementos e solicitar a exclusão de um numero, e esse numero for o ultimo da lista, também da crash.

---

Segue o código:

```
class Node{

    public:

        int value;
        Node *next;

        Node(){
            next = NULL;
        }

};
```

---

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class List{

    public:

        Node *head;
        Node *tail;

        Lists(){
            head = NULL;
            tail = NULL;
        }



        void push_back(int num){

            Node *node = new Node;
            node->value = num;

            if(head == NULL){
                head = node;
                tail = node;    
            }else{
                Node *aux = tail;
                tail = node;
                aux->next = node;   
            }
        }



        void print(){

            if(head == NULL){
                cout << "A lista esta vazia, nao ha nada a exibir\n";
                return;
            }else{

                Node *print = head;

                cout << "Elementos da lista: ";
                while(print != NULL){
                    cout << print->value << " ";
                    print = print->next;
                }

                cout << endl;

            }

        }

        void push_after_aleatory(int num,Node *p){

            if(p == tail){
                return push_back(num);
            }else{
                Node *node = new Node;
                node->value = num;
                node->next = p->next;
                p->next = node;
                return; 
            }

        }

        void delete_after_aleatory1(Node *p){

            if(head == NULL){
                cout << "A lista esta vazia,nao ha nada a excluir\n";
                return;
            }

            if(p == tail){
                cout << "Nao e possivel excluir, nao ha nenhum elemento apos o no repassado\n";
                return;
            }

            if(p == head){

                if(head->next != NULL){

                    Node *aux = head->next;

                    head->next = head->next->next;
                    cout << "Exclusao concluida\n";

                    delete aux;

                    return;

                }

                cout << "A lista possui apenas um elemento, nao e possivel excluir";
                return;

            }else{

                Node *aux = p->next;

                p->next = p->next->next;
                cout << "Exclusao concluida\n";

                delete aux;

                return;

            }

        }

        void delete_find_number(int num){


            if(head == NULL){

                cout << "A lista esta vazia, nao ha nada a excluir\n";
                return;

            }


            if(tail->value == num){

                Node *aux = tail;
                Node *pointer = head;

                while(pointer->next != tail){
                    pointer = pointer->next;
                }

                tail = pointer;
                tail->next = NULL;

                delete aux;         
                return;

            }else if(head->value == num){

                Node *aux = head;

                head = head->next;
                delete aux;
                return;

            }else{

                Node *node = head;

                while(node != NULL){


                if(node->next->value == num){

                    Node *aux = node->next; 
                    node = node->next->next;

                    aux->next = NULL;
                    delete aux;
                    return;

                }

                node = node->next;

                }

            }

            cout << "Elemento nao encontrado, nao e possivel excluir\n";

        }

};
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    List list;
    int sentinela,numero;

    while(sentinela != 5){

        system("cls");
        cout << "Opcoes do menu:\n\n1-Inserir\n2-Excluir(parametro ponteiro)\n3-Excluir(parametro numero)\n4-Exbir a lista\n5-Sair\n\nOpcao desejada: ";
        cin >> sentinela;

        if(sentinela == 1){
            system("cls");
            cout << "Digite um numero: ";
            cin >> numero;
            list.push_back(numero);
        }

        if(sentinela == 2){
            system("cls");
            list.delete_after_aleatory1(list.head);
            system("PAUSE");
        }

        if(sentinela == 3){
            system("cls");
            cout << "Digite um numero: ";
            cin >> numero;
            list.delete_find_number(numero);
            system("PAUSE");
        }

        if(sentinela == 4){
            system("cls");
            list.print();
            system("PAUSE");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Tem muita coisa que não está fazendo e outra errada. Faltam `delete` em toda a vez que remove um nó. Para remover o nó tem de alterar o ponteiro a partir do anterior. As classes devem ter o nome no singular, etc..

Comment: if(node->next->value == num) deveria ser if(node->value == num).. da forma que esta você não verifica se o valor passado existe no primeiro elemento.. e se por acaso chegar ao final da lista sem encontrar vc vai tentar acessar o next que é null... e vai dar pal. No entanto, como é uma lista simples. pra vc remover o ultimo elemento vc tem q ter uma referencia ao anterior, vc deve atualizar seu código para que, ou vc mantenha essa referencia e envie para seu métodos removerem corretamente. ou envie ambos nodos (o anterior e o que irá editar) para vc poder remover corretamente nesses casos.

Comment: No método de pesquisa você poderia verificar primeiramente se o valor que vc está buscando existe em algum dos extremos, só verifica o meio da lista caso num != tail->value e head->value. dai vc roda teu while enquanto node != tail, evita null pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, não programo em C++ .. no entanto esse é um problema bastante comum.
Então fiz uma solução rapidinho aqui em Javascript para que você possa dar uma olhada na lógica. Não está completo (nem perfeito), no entanto trata essa questão de escanear a lista em busca do elemento. Remove no inicio, meio e fim sem problemas.

Espero que te ajude a solucionar teu bug. Caso precisar posso escrever esse código em C (com um pouco de tempo).

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
};

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
  }

  insert(value) {
    let node = new Node(value);
    if (this.head == null) {
      this.head = node;
      this.tail = this.head;
    } else {
      this.tail.next = node;
      this.tail = this.tail.next;
    }
  }

  remove(value) {
    let tmp = null;
    if (this.head.value === value) {
      tmp = this.head;
      this.head = this.head.next;
    } else { // scan list
      let aux = this.head;
      while (aux.next != null) {
        if (aux.next.value === value) {
          tmp = aux.next;

          aux.next = aux.next.next; //update reference.
        }
        if (aux.next != null) {
          aux = aux.next; //move to next. 
        }
      }
    }

    return tmp;
  }

  print() {
    let aux = this.head;
    while (aux != null) {
      console.log(aux.value);
      aux = aux.next;
    }
    console.log("------------------------------")
  }
};

// Testando código....
let run = new LinkedList();

run.insert(1);
run.insert(2);
run.insert(3);
run.insert(4);
run.insert(5);

run.print();

run.remove(4);
run.print();
run.remove(1);
run.print();
run.remove(5);
run.print();
```

Comment: Muito obg pela ajuda mano, vou tentar implementar essas mudanças no codigo